# JS click function not triggered when I click on Icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on icon my jQuery click function is not triggered. I am not sure what's wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

**jQuery**

```
 $("document").ready(function(){
     $("#abc").click(function() {
         $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
             modal: true,
             width: 400,
             height: 400,
         });
     });
 });
```

Now here is the image and this is how I am linking.

```
 echo '<td>' . '<img src="edit.png" style = "height:35px;margin-left :8px;" id="abc">' . '</td>';
```

And here is my form that will pop as dialog!

```
<body>

     <div id="dialog-confirm" style="display:none;">
         <form>      
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="name" id="name" required>
            <label for="number">Number</label>
            <input type="number" id="number" required>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" required>
            <input type="submit" id="submit">
            <input type="submit" id="cancel" value="Cancel">
        </form>
    </div>


</body>
```

Any help?

Here is the complete page:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jq‌​uery-ui.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>

    <script src="smoke.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/venview.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function deleterecord ( id ) {
            smoke.confirm("Do you want to delete?", function(result){
                if(result)
                {
                    window.location.href = 'delete_ven.php?id=' + id;
                }
                else{
                    header("Location: ven_view.php");
                }});

        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#abc").click(function() {
                $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    width: 400,
                    height: 400
                });
            });
        });
        $("#submit").click (function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var name = $("#name").val;
            var num= $("#number").val;
            var email = $("#email").val;
            var dataString = 'name'+name+'number'+num+'email'+email;
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:dataString,
                url:'edit_ven.php',
                success:function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <?php




    include 'includes/head.php'; 
    include 'ven_connect.php';
    include "dashboard.php";


    if (isset($_GET["page"])) 
    { 
        $page  = (int) $_GET["page"]; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $page=1; 
    }; 
    $start_from = ($page-1) * 4; 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn , "SELECT * FROM vendor LIMIT $start_from, 4") or die (mysqli_error ($conn));

    echo "<table title='Vendors'>";
    echo '<tr>';
    echo    "<th>Sr</th>";
    echo    "<th>Edit</th>";
    echo    "<th>Delete</th>";
    echo    "<th>Name</th>";
    echo    "<th>PhoneNo</th>";
    echo    "<th>Email</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {

            // display the contents of each row into a table
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . '<img src="edit.png" style = "height:35px;margin-left :8px;" id="abc">' . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . '<img src="delete.png" style = "height:35px;margin-left :8px;" onclick = "deleterecord('.$row['id'].')">' . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['Number'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
        echo "</tr>"; 
    } 
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "</table>";
    ?>
    <body>

        <div id="dialog-confirm" style="display:none;">
            <form>      
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="name" id="name" required>
                <label for="number">Number</label>
                <input type="number" id="number" required>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" required>
                <input type="submit" id="update">
                <input type="submit" id="cancel" value="Cancel">
            </form>
        </div>


    </body>
    <?php
    //Pagination!!  
    if($page > 1)
    {

        $prev= $page - 1;

        echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$prev'>Prev</a> ";
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn , "SELECT * FROM vendor") or die (mysqli_error ($conn));
    $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 4); 

    $range = 3;


    for ($x = ($page - $range); $x <($page + $range); $x++) {

        if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $total_pages)) {

            if ($x == $page) {

                echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";

            } 

            else {

                echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$x'>$x</a> ";
            } 
        } 
    } 
    if($page != $total_pages)
    {
        $nextpage=$page+1;
        echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$nextpage'>Next</a> ";
    }






    ?>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is error on console???

Comment: Make sure `#abc` is unique on page

Comment: What is the error in console?

Comment: is your img added dynamically later after page is already loaded?

Comment: Here is the error

Underlined  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({

error: Uncaught Typeerror: $(...).dialog is not a function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the quotes around document:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // remove the quotes here arround document
    $("#abc").click(function() {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            height: 400 // remove the comma here
        });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery UI

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDesign/572x62qc/)**

**Update**

```
<!doctype HTML>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jq‌​uery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/venview.css">
</head>
<body>

    // other code

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="smoke.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function deleterecord ( id ) {
            smoke.confirm("Do you want to delete?", function(result){
                if(result)
                {
                    window.location.href = 'delete_ven.php?id=' + id;
                }
                else{
                    header("Location: ven_view.php");
                }});

        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#abc").click(function() {
                $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    width: 400,
                    height: 400
                });
            });
        });
        $("#submit").click (function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var name = $("#name").val;
            var num= $("#number").val;
            var email = $("#email").val;
            var dataString = 'name'+name+'number'+num+'email'+email;
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:dataString,
                url:'edit_ven.php',
                success:function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have tested it both with and without quotes. This is not the issue.

Comment: Like in the other comments mentioned, do you have errors in your error console?

Comment: @RayaanKhan Remove also the comma after the height value ( view answer )

Comment: Here is the error

Underlined  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({

error: Uncaught Typeerror: $(...).dialog is not a function

Comment: Make sure you have included all js files in your project! View update!

Comment: i am using Google CDN

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes but you also need the jQuery UI which contains the dialog function

Comment: This Erroe (Here is the error Underlined $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({ error: Uncaught Typeerror: $(...).dialog is not a function ) only shows up the moment I click on my image.

Comment: Here is the one for dialog: <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: if you use that, it works also! Make sure you added these libraries at the bottom just before the closing body tag!

Comment: Don't we put scritp inside head? I just placed it before the closing body tag it worked but dialog is no more a dialog messed up. It should look like the one in your JS fiddle but unfortunately it does not. Check it!

http://imagehosting.io/image/v4w

Comment: Your js files needs to be at the bootom just before the closing body tag. Your link stylesheets needs to be in your head.

Comment: Did you check image? Why dialog is a complete mess?

Comment: Jup you need to add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">` in your head section

Comment: Nothing changed. Still messed up.

Comment: Can you post your entre html page in your question? From doctype till the end

Comment: View my update, also you have 2 body tags???? Remove the body tags arround your dialog!!!

Comment: I implemented it first in a seperate file and then integrated here. So, mistakenly there's body tags.

Still messed up :(

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I just added <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">  and it worked :)